# Cannot clone object error when using gridsearchCV in a pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I am making a pipeline consisting of a tfidf vectorizer and an xgboost classifier and I am trying to find the optimal parameters for the vectorizer for my problem. I however get the following error:

`Cannot clone object Text2TfIdfTransformer(max_df=0.5, max_features=1000), as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter max_df.`

Here is the code:

```
class Text2TfIdfTransformer(BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self, max_df = 1, max_features = 3000):
        self._model = TfidfVectorizer(max_df, max_features, sublinear_tf=True)
        pass

    def fit(self, data, df_y=None):
        self._model.fit(data)
        return self

    def transform(self, text):
        return self._model.transform(text)
    


pl_xgb_tf_idf = Pipeline(steps=[('tfidf',Text2TfIdfTransformer()),
                         ('xgboost', XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax'))])


parameters = {'tfidf__max_df':[.5,.6], 'tfidf__max_features': [1000]}
grid = GridSearchCV(pl_xgb_tf_idf, param_grid=parameters, cv=5)
grid.fit(X,labels)
```

I'm not sure if I should declare the variables max_df and max_features when calling **init** but if I don't declare them here I get another error (that the estimator doesn't have any variables)

I am sure I am missing something basic but I can't find what it is exactly, any help would be greatly appreciated!

If there is some important information missing, please ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the argument names of the fit and transform function of the parent class

```
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self._model.fit(X)
        return self

    def transform(self, x):
        return self._model.transform(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be declaring the parameters in `__init __` in order to do run a gridsearch on them, otherwise you are breaking the sklearn API conventions.

This should fix your issue:

```
def __init__(self, max_df = 1, max_features = 3000):
    self.max_df = max_df
    self.max_features = max_features
    self._model = TfidfVectorizer(self.max_df, self.max_features, sublinear_tf=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, the code is running at least but I am noticing some strange behavior. Whatever parameters I am passing, it seems to be only doing the calculations with the default parameters I am passing when initializing.
I am starting to suspect that it is because gridsearchCV is only applicable when passing parameters for the last stage of the pipeline? But I would be surprised if this were to be true. (When passing multiple options in my parameters, all the scores in the cross validation are identical) Any reason why this might happen? I can always share more code if necessary!